# Adding more than 8 images on one slide in keynote

Tags: mac, iwork-keynote, iwork

I'm making a poster size slide on keynote.

I cannot insert more than 8 images on one slide. When I do, i get this error:

```
The file wasn’t added to the slide because the slide is full.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a graphics editing program like [Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/) to combine the images into one.